# How to create a Default Endpoint in wso2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have different  services and there respective endpoints in my WSO2 DSS like

```
http://localhost:9764/services/Get_details/ 

http://localhost:9764/services/muser_DataService/
```

etc

so,when am creating a proxy service in WSO2 ESB i want to give a default endpoint in my proxy rather then the particular endpoint in DSS

For this approach i used Recipient List Group as shown below

```
<endpoint xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="Endpoint">
```

```
  <endpoint name="null_value">
     <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/null_value/">
        <suspendOnFailure>
           <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
           <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
           <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>
     </address>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint name="Get_details">
     <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/Get_details/">
        <suspendOnFailure>
           <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
           <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
           <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>
     </address>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint name="Get_geodetails">
     <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/Get_geodetails/">
        <suspendOnFailure>
           <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
           <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
           <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>
     </address>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint name="muser_DataService">
     <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/muser_DataService/">
        <suspendOnFailure>
           <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
           <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
           <retryDelay>0</retryDelay>
        </markForSuspension>
     </address>
  </endpoint>
```

But when am using this endpoint in my proxy, process is failing to find the required endpoint in the created Recipient List Group and throwing an error as shown below

```
"Fault":{"faultcode":"axis2ns2:Client","faultstring":"The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is \/services\/Get_details\/ and the WSA Action = null. If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.","detail":""}
```

What can be done for a successful execution......

Answer (score 0):

Recipient endpoint is used for different purpose. You should have different endpoint definition, if your backend service URL is different. Then use proper endpoint in your proxy.